# Creative ways to display long lists

Tags: website-design

I am working on redesigning a page that displays a 2 column table of approximately 200 manufacturer names.  The page becomes very long but so far isn't incredibly unmanageable, but I'm trying to apply a more futuristic design.

I provided a sample page to the client with a 5 column table of smaller logos, but due to the vast diversity of colors in the logos it made the page look extremely busy.

The client does not want to have users click to view the manufacturer list (I proposed some jQuery goodness broken down by category).

Anyway, just thought I'd check to see if anybody has any samples of displaying longer lists as I'm not the most creative person around.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Hmm... I think aside cool design you should also think on usability.

Long lists tires anyone. My suggestion, if possible under your implementation, is to paginate results, showing just 20-50 results per page, in alphabetical order.

Simple, gives you a breathe in layout, and any person can use easily.

Comment: This is the correct answer. There's simply no other solution other than pagination for showing large result sets.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using bigger padding values on the table cells, thus making some visual space.

Answer (score 0):

You can make attractive timeline where all the columns may seem as they are linked by some bakeground image.
Replace standard scroll bar with some advanced/modern control like slider etc.

Comment: Do you have a sample somewhere?

Comment: i seen it on a site.i'll serach &'ll suggest u soon

Comment: Just see the menu used in this demo http://demo.woothemes.com/chapters/ from woothemes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too obvious, but what about using the js/code used for google images search or shoutcast.com (once you click in a category, showing all radio stations at the right)

Basically it "hides" the content but when click in a large 2.0ish button of Show More, there's no reload, but an instant, non moving deploy of more content. Imo that's best.

Being used lately in many places.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but they don't want to break these down into categories.  This is supposed to be more of a View All option.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest utilizing the datatables plugin for jQuery (at datatables.net)
Just have a look at their examples and see if it suits your needs.